# From axis and angle of rotation to rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

I have the rotation axis  $\mathbb{R} (1, 1, -1)$ and the angle $\pi/4$.

How do I compute the rotation matrix?

I know the inverse process in which you use $trace(M) = 1 - 2cos(\theta)$ to get the angle and $Ax = x$ to get the axis but I couldn't really apply that in an "inversed" way.

Comment: Where does your formulas for $tr(M)$ and $Ax=x$ come from?

Answer (score 0):

Look up [Rodrigues' formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula), which does exactly this.